# ¿Cómo hacer una función que se renombre a si misma?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, funciones

Por necesidades del sistema, necesito que una función denominada `cargarSelect`, se renombre a `cargarSelect1`, `cargarSelect2` ... y así sucesivamente dependiendo de la cantidad de modales que sean generado, desde la llamada del botón de apertura del modal 1 debería cargarse `cargarSelect1(parametro)`.  ¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer esto?

Mi botón:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info transfer"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTransferirResguardo<?= $i+1?>" id="<?= $i+1?>" data-keyboard="false" data_backdrop="static" title="TRANSFERENCIA DEL ACTIVO"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer" onclick="cargarSelect(<?=$i+1?>)"></span></button>
```

Comment: y porqué no pasar el elemento "this" como parámetro a tu función cargarSelect para que el sistema sepa qué debe hacer?

Comment: Me podrías explicar como hacer eso ? Gracias

Comment: Si al final tu funcion cargarSelect hara lo mismo porque crear funciones repetidas? Mejor explica en tu pregunta que pretendes hacer con cada modal y agrega el codigo de cargarSelect para que te puedan sugerir una mejor respuesta

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con @MiguelZarate e incluso iría más lejos: ¿para qué necesitas un modal aquí? Hoy día puedes prescindir totalmente del uso de modales incluso para operaciones complicadas como comunicación cliente/servidor que se pueden hacer por mediación de Ajax, ganando además en mejor experiencia del usuario.

Comment: El modal es para mostrar la información de cada row de una tabla, y los combox para seleccionar a la persona que le sera reasignado un bien, he tenido varios problemas incluso desde como enviar la información del row a la ventana modal, y luego con los selects, estoy atorado ahi. Entiendo perfecamente que con una sola funcion deberia funcionar, pero no resulta, asi que me dijeron, ponle la funcion a cada modal, incluso a nivel del modal yo preferiría solo tener un modal y ahi cargar los datos pero no lo pude implementar en Ajax y eso me complico las cosas.  Saludo